# Initializing a BufferedReader (JAVA)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, bufferedreader

I am currently writing a method that tests if an input String (a password) contains a part of a dictionary. The dictionary is a simple txt file with one word per line. I now want to check every line of the dictionary if it is contained in the input String. The code below should work for me:

```
public boolean dictionaryCheck(String pLine)
{
  BufferedReader myReader;
  String currentLine;
  try
  {
    myReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dict.txt"));
    while(myReader.readLine() != null)
    {
      currentLine = myReader.readLine();
      if(pLine.contains(currentLine))
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception e){System.out.println("Error: " + e);}
  return true;
}
```

The problem is that when I run the method with any parameter String I get the following error:

`Error: java.lang.NullPointerException`

So I assume that the BufferedReader is not initialized correctly.

Any suggestions of how to fix this? The code seems fine to me, but I might overlook a mistake.

Thanks in advance,

Joe Cocker

Comment: can you add the full stacktrace?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two calls to readLine() - the inner call could be returning null

```
while( (currentLine = myReader.readLine()) != null)
{
  if(pLine.contains(currentLine))
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```